# Почему RecyclerView null?

Tags: java, android

Код фрагмента:

```
public class ResultsFragment extends Fragment {
    private String id;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_results, container, false);

        ActivityFragments activityFragments = (ActivityFragments) getActivity();
        id = activityFragments.getMyData();


       // AllResultPresenter allResultPresenter = new AllResultPresenter(id,ResultsFragment.this);  

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       // super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_all);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        final LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        AllResultPresenter allResultPresenter = new AllResultPresenter(id,ResultsFragment.this);

    }

    public void showAllResult(ArrayList<Result> allResultResponses) {
        recyclerView.setAdapter(new AllResultsAdapter(this, allResultResponses));
    }
}
```

А вот код Presenter:

```
public class AllResultPresenter {
    private ResultsFragment resultsFragment;
    private ArrayList<Result> results;
    private String id;

    public AllResultPresenter(String mId, final ResultsFragment mResultsFragment) {
        this.id = mId;
        this.resultsFragment = mResultsFragment;
        results = new ArrayList<>();   

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("https://asthmacare.ru/")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
        retrofit.create(API.class).getAllResultResponse(id).enqueue(new Callback<AllResultResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<AllResultResponse> call, Response<AllResultResponse> response) {
                //ArrayList<allRes>  = response.body().getResults();
               results = response.body().getResults();
                resultsFragment.showAllResult(results); 

               }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<AllResultResponse> call, Throwable t) {

            }    
        });
    }
}
```

Почему-то вылетает ошибка:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(boolean)' on a
>   null object reference

Comment: Сделайте после установки LayoutManager

Comment: @pavel163 что сделайте?

Comment: recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

Answer (score 1):

Во первых делать `recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_all);` лучше в `onCreateView`. И раз он не находит вьюшку значит нужно проверить id этого RecyclerView в `R.layout.fragment_results`.

Comment: У меня отельная хмл в которой RelativeLayout , а в ней Recycler View.
В RelativeLayout есть такие параметры: showIn:разметкаФрагмента и Context:ActivityФрагмента.

Comment: Я это понимаю. До сих пор вылетает NPE?